# Spring batch custom DB schema init

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-batch

My spring-boot configuration is:

```
spring:
  profiles: database
  datasource:
    platform: mysql
    continueOnError: false
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    username: root
    data: data-mysql.sql
    schema: schema-mysql.sql
  batch:
    initializer:
      enabled: true
    initialize-schema: always
    job:
      enabled: true
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
```

My expectation is:

- `spring-batch` `schema` will be created each time from very beginning;
- `customer` table specified in the `schema-mysql.sql` will be created every start time;
- `customer` data will specified in the `data-mysql.sql` be populated every start time;

But the actual result is:

- `spring-batch` `schema` is created only first time;
- `customer` table never populated with data;
- `customer` table never created;

### Question:

How should I change my configuration to get next result:

- I'm ok if `spring-batch` `schema` is created only once or every start time (but it should be created for absence case);
- `customer` table should be created only once or every time;
- `customer` table should be populated with data if no data there.

### Details:

- spring-boot 2.2.0.M3;
- Gradle 5.4.1;
- mariadb.

Comment: First remove  hibernate: ddl-auto: create-drop because you are already using schema.sql

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, thanks. I know, that is not required for my purpose, but I tried a lot of different combinations and that doesn't work any way. (I mean `ddl-auto` = `never` or absent also doesn't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see that you configured to execute the schema and data file.

You have to add:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        initialization-mode: always
```